# How to fix "invalid syntax for integer : 'NUM'

Tags: mysql, sql, csv, pgadmin

I have this CSV file and I want to copy it to the table I created but pgadmin outputs:

> ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: "NUM" CONTEXT: COPY tickets,
>   line 1, column num: "NUM" SQL state: 22P02

The `COPY` code :

```
copy TICKETS(NUM,KIND,LOCATIONS,PRICE,DATES,CAT)
FROM 'C:\tmp\tickets.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV
```

The CSV file:

[image]

Comment: It seems that the error is related to the first row of your CSV file, which contains column headers. Use the `HEADER` option: "Specifies that the file contains a header line with the names of each column in the file ... and on input, the first line is ignored," ([PostgreSQL COPY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/sql-copy.html)). Also see [How to make Postgres Copy ignore first line of large txt file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11788411/924299).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you try this way:

```
create table TICKETS(
  NUM INT,
  KIND INT,
  LOCATION VARCHAR(100),
  PRICE INT,
  DATE DATE,
  CAT CHAR(1)
)

LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/tmp/tickets.csv' 
INTO TABLE TICKETS
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

The important point is the last line `IGNORE 1 ROWS` excludes the titles, and no error raises.

Comment: I think the copy code is ok because i used it before with another db . Its propably something in the file for some reason it doesnt read "1" as integer

Comment: Oh the ignore 1 rows it actually fixed it thank you!!